# Where is the image cached/saved after input type file take from camera?

Tags: android, ios, html, forms

I have a HTML that has a form that has `<input type=“file” accept=“image/*” capture=“camera”>`

If I take a picture on my mobile and post the form, the image is uploaded but (at least in Android and iOS), it is not stored in Photos. So it seems it is temporarily saved on some folder. Is it deleted after the image is submitted? Or is it somehow possible to access (the original image) without resorting to AJAX? Is there some HTML5 way of doing it? Or is there some Android or iOS specific implementation?

Comment: How are you taking this image exactly?, is a separate window launching with camera and you take image?

Comment: Yes, it is a separate window (camera app) launched after I click the input button. Say, in desktop, it would normally pupup the file browser picker. On mobile, it could launch the camera app.

Comment: So according to your comment I can deduce that its the native camera app that gets launched, what happens here is that the captured image is converted to bitmap and held in memory, which is then sent to the server with your post request, so the photo is not actually saved to a physical location

Comment: Is the bitmap held in memory automatically lost after the post request to the server? Or can it still be accessed for a succeeding request?

Comment: I don't know if you can do it through html, but in native android what you do is you launch camera activity, and after user clicks the photo, the bitmap data is returned to the result method, where we can do whatever we want with the bitmap obtained, like compressing to jpg/ saving it in storage etc

Comment: Interesting question